# How do I install a Yahoo! Connected TV Widget on a TV so I can test it?

Tags: javascript, yahoo-widgets

I am developing a Yahoo! Connected TV Widget (using tools including the simulator provided by Yahoo!)  How can I install my widget on a real TV so that I can test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a connected TV from any of the supported OEMs (Sony, Samsung, LG, VIZIO) to test your widget.

From the TV open the Widget Gallery, hit the green button, go to the Developer Settings and get your Developer Code.

Go to: http://gallery.tv.widgets.yahoo.com/publisher/ and upload your widget to test on the TV.

It's really easy to test on a real device.

Answer (score 2):

I think the installation of widget is tightly controlled by Yahoo, so it has to go through their QA approval process and only then it's released for public. I don't think you can install it directly on any TV.

But you can try the **Widget Development Simulator** to test.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, Yahoo! Connected TV isn't as popular a development target as some others.  I am aware of and using the simulator Yahoo! provides.  But I don't believe it's really testing till it's on the real hardware.  I suspect your answer is close to the truth, but all the Yahoo! message boards about the topic seem to be very slyly not saying "No, you can't put your app on your TV without our permission."

Comment: @jsl4tv - the devil is in the details. Take a look at Yahoo's developer terms of use, should be hidden somewhere.

http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/tvwidget/tvwidget-4251.html

Comment: @SoftwareGeek - OMG, you are right.  Naturally the important parts of the docs are in the EULA's and TOS's.  Sigh....

What is the right way to collect the relevant parts of the contract, hook them up to your answer, and give you credit?  Should I (try) to edit your answer?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't even have enough rep to upvote.  *And* I finally got the real answer but it was like pulling teeth.  I'll answer my own question... sigh...

Comment: @jsl4tv - glad to know you found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation Yahoo! provides for deploying widgets to TV's before they have passed Yahoo! QA is not available online, but is installed as part of the WDK.  I found the document finally in

```
/usr/local/share/WDK/doc/YWE_Developer_Guide.pdf
```

There are 3 options

- Use an OEM device with special interfaces
- Use the pre-publish website as Connected TV describes above (thanks!)
- Do the whole Yahoo! QA process and make the widget available to the world